# How to keep sidebar width from changing when extending length of sidebar in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

When running the below MWE code, note that in the Dynamic tab, when you click on the "Show" button, a long matrix input grid pops up underneath, extending the length of the sidebar panel. And when you click "Hide", the matrix input grid disappears. This all works fine. But when clicking "Show" the width of the sidebar panel shrinks to make room for the default vertical viewing slider on the right as a result of the sidebar panel extending below the screen. Is there a way to keep the width of the sidebar panel from changing when the default vertical viewing slider appears on the right? If something needs to shrink to accommodate that slider, I'd rather have it be the main panel.

```
library(shiny) 
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

# --- Initial values for performance vectors input matrix
m2 <- function(x) {matrix(c(1:40), 20, 2)}

# --- MatrixInput function to use for performance vector
matrix2.input <- function(x) {matrixInput(
    x,
    value = {m2()},
    rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")} 

ui <- 
pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Model"),
  sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==1",
                     numericInput("begin.bal","Beginning balance:",value=100000,step=1000),
                     sliderInput("periods", "Number of periods to model:",min=1,max=120,value=60),
                     h5(strong("Vectorize performance variable:")), 
                     
                     # Action buttons to conditionally show/hide performance vectors --->
                     useShinyjs(),
                     actionButton('showPerfVectorBtn', 'Show'), 
                     actionButton('hidePerfVectorBtn', 'Hide'), 
                     uiOutput("Vectors")),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==2",
                     selectInput("dataset", "select the desired dataset", 
                                 choices=ls('package:datasets'), 
                                 selected = "")), 
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==3",uiOutput("varx"),uiOutput("vary"))
  ), # close sidebar panel
  
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Dynamic", value=1,
          helpText("Pending...")),
      tabPanel("Data", value=2, 
          conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==1", verbatimTextOutput("dat")),
          conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==2", verbatimTextOutput("struct")),
          conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice==3", verbatimTextOutput("summary"))),
      tabPanel("Plot", value=3, plotOutput("plot")), 
      
      id = "tabselected"
    ) # close tabset panel
  ) # close main panel
) # close page with sidebar

 server <- function(input,output)({

# --- Set reactive input variables 
 periods    <-  reactive(input$periods)
 yld_input  <-  reactive(input$yld_input)
 
# --- Action buttons to conditionally show/hide performance vector
 output$Vectors <- renderUI({
   req(input$showPerfVectorBtn)
    tagList(matrix2.input("yld_input")) # close tag list    
  }) # close render UI
   
observeEvent(input$showPerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
observeEvent(input$hidePerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})

}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Instead of showing all the rows can you show only few rows?

Comment: Problem is each one of the input matrices automatically extends based on user inputs, by intentional design. Most users will have expanded each one of the 4 matrices to about 8 rows each, or longer, creating a very long sidebar. Which is fine, and how I would like it to work. But keeping the sidebar width fixed as its length extends would result in a more professional-looking App.